# kendo datasource sending jquery string

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-datasource

I have this Kendo UI datasource.  I am trying to pass the data parameter

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "http://clientstoprofits.paupertopresident.com/api/Schedule/Tasks_Read",
        data:{
            UserId:id,
            startDate:startTime
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    },
```

but the only thing that is being sent is

```
Request URL:http://mydomain.com/api/Schedule/Tasks_Read?callback=jQuery19107631381487008184_1398210088201&_=1398210088207
```

can anybody tell me why i am getting this callback=Jquery*?

Comment: That's the name of the callback jQuery created for this JSONP request. What's the problem?

Comment: data:{UserId:id,startDate:startTime} parameter is not being passed

Comment: you can't post data with JSONP; encode the user id and start date as url params instead

Comment: that did thanks...if u provide the answer ill check it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback url parameter is the name of the callback jQuery created for this JSONP request (for a more detailed explanation, take a look at the `dataType` option for [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

As to why your data is not being sent: you can only do that with POST requests, and JSONP requests are by definition GET requests. So you'll have to encode the user id and start date as url params instead.